# CASE WHEN variable THEN IN

Tags: sql, case

Is it possible to achieve something similar to this

```
WHERE t.userid in 
    CASE @UserID WHEN 0 THEN (10288,10364,10404,10445,10469,10516,10585) 
    ELSE  t.userid in (1) END
```

Comment: I don't get it why the down vote though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with `case`.  Just use boolean expressions:

```
WHERE (@UserId = 0 AND
       t.userid IN (10288, 10364, 10404, 10445, 10469, 10516, 10585)
      ) OR
      (@UserId <> 0 AND t.userid = 1)
```

Note:  If `@UserId` could be `NULL`, you need to take that into account as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
WHERE (@UserId = 0 and t.userid IN (10288,10364,10404,10445,10469,10516,10585)) OR (t.userid = 1)
```